# Reasoning CSIR NET June 15

Tags: pattern, letter-sequence

This question was asked in NET. I am unable to solve it.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.

> aN is reversed Na which is **S**odium

2.

> eF is reversed Fe which is **I**ron

3.

> gH is reversed Hg which is **M**ercury

answer:

> nS is reversed Sn which is: **T**in so **1**